# Renaming file names using a csv dictionary

Tags: python, csv

There are quite a few threads on the website regarding this question.
But does not answer my question.
I'm looking to rename folders with community code to community name.
I keep getting Windows error :file specified not found.
Here is sample code

```
 import csv,os
 path=r"files location"
 reader = csv.reader(open(path+'\CommunityDictionary.csv', 'rb'))

 cdict = {}
 for row in reader:
 sym, community = row
 cdict[sym] = community
 dir=r"root folder path" #folder contains sub folders with Abbreviatedcodes#

 for folder in os.walk(dir):
    for folder in cdict:
       os.rename(os.path.join(dir,folder), os.path.join(dir,cdict[folder]))
```

If any body could point out what I'm doing wrong ,would be greatly appreciated.
The same code worked a couple weeks ago but not now.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? You could check it with `os.path.exists('path_to_your_csv')`. Also, you might want to use `os.path.join` to create the path instead.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\gis\temp\AddressMapbook\scripts\NeighbourhoodTest1_Step3.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.rename(os.path.join(dir,folder), os.path.join(dir,cdict[folder]))
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: @ double_j ,I have posted the Trace back here

Comment: I would print out the values of `os.path.join(dir,folder)` and `os.path.join(dir,cdict[folder])` to see what filename you are trying to rename and make sure that file really does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks double_j !!

I figured that my csv has a key value that does not exist in my files that I'm trying to rename.
The code posted in my question works like a charm !!.